# Handler for when text is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selected text event trigger in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545018/selected-text-event-trigger-in-javascript)
>   [jquery: select text event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367353/jquery-select-text-event)

Is there a handler/listener in javascript which determines when text is selected in a certain element? Raw Javascript is fine, although something jQuery would be preferred. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of element?  For example, the `input` tag has an `onselect` event.

Comment: this is probably a question asked repetitively so bear with me- is there anywhere we can suggest features for js to implement in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event for selection, but you can use `document.getSelection` to access text that may be currently selected. You can bind a handler to `onmouseup` or `onkeyup`, etc.

Comment: Which handler do you think would be more suitable?

Comment: I would say onmouseup if your website is desktop-based. Not sure what event gets fired on touch devices if your site is for mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

Rangy comes with all kinds of goodies related to manipulating text selection: http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Using it with jQuery is incredibly simple. For example:

```
$( 'body' ).on( 'mouseup', function(){
  var sel = rangy.getSelection();
  if( sel.length > 0 ){
    console.log( sel );
  }
});
```

Good luck!